# menu and button background color problem - gtk theme

Tags: themes, menu, 14.10

I use Ubuntu 14.10, I don't have this problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,

When I use GTK Theme the menu and button background not work good in all there.

Sample:

[image: menu bg not worked any there]

[image: button background problem]

What is the problem? why this problem not exists in 14.04 ?

Comment: It's possible that 14.10 doesn't use the same GNOME as 14.04 and that the theme you're using hasn't been updated to reflect the changes.